# How do i convert a bitmap image to emgu image?

Tags: image, converters, emgucv

I need to convert a bitmap image to a Image format image so that I can display it in my image box. Please help thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is also possible to create an Image from a .Net Bitmap object. The code in C# would be

```
 Image<Bgr, Byte> img = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(bmp); //where bmp is a Bitmap
```

You can find the official documnetation [here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images#Creating_image_from_Bitmap)